# Looking for working Flex (or Flash) websocket client

Tags: ruby, apache-flex, air, websocket

I'm working on what should become a quiz-like mobile app. The idea is to combine a Ruby websocket server (or preferably Juggernaut as the app has chat functionality) with an AIR client.

In the past few days I've been trying different web socket servers with multiple Flex code snippets but I can't get any of the clients functioning. Looks like the connection is made  but I get the idea that the client is unable to perform the handshake correctly (and subsequently disconnects). A lot of the Flash/Flex code snippets I found are a few years old so my guess is that the web socket protocol has evolved in the mean time without the Flash/Flex code bases getting these updates.

So, I'm appreciating any help in locating a reliable Flash/Flex code snippet that works with any web socket server (or preferably Juggernaut).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Kaazing supports a number of client technologies out-of-the-box including Flash, Flex, and Air [disclaimer: I'm Kaazing's Developer Evangelist].
Here are a couple of links for you to check it out:

- [Hosted Flash and Flex Demo](http://demo.kaazing.com/demo/jms/flash/?d=stomp-jms-flash): This is a demo of a Flex JMS Web client that communicates directly with a message broker to perform Stomp commands.
- [Hosted demos for a variety of client technologies](http://demo.kaazing.com/demo/jms/javascript/) - see links on the left to select your client technology
- [Implementing a Stomp Protocol Client in Adobe Flex](http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/dragonfire/tutorial-protocol-client-flex.html) - a step-by-step guide
- [Creating an XMPP-Driven Application in Adobe Flex](http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/dragonfire/tutorial-xmpp-flex.html) - a step-by-step guide

Comment: These links are all dead at this point. Kaazing has discontinued support for Flash/Flex.